# Why does does an in-bounds array access cause a segfault in LLVM IR?

Tags: segmentation-fault, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm seeing some very surprising behaviour debugging a segfault in LLVM IR. Consider the code:

```
declare void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i32(i8* nocapture, i8, i32, i32, i1)

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %cells = alloca i8, i32 9
  %offset_cell_ptr = getelementptr i8* %cells, i32 0
  call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i32(i8* %offset_cell_ptr, i8 0, i32 9, i32 1, i1 true)

  %cell_index_ptr = alloca i32
  store i32 0, i32* %cell_index_ptr

  ; This is an out-of-bounds memory access.
  %target_cell_ptr = getelementptr i8* %cells, i32 -1
  %target_cell_val = load i8* %target_cell_ptr
  %new_target_val = add i8 %target_cell_val, 11
  store i8 %new_target_val, i8* %target_cell_ptr

  ; This memory access is in bounds.
  %cell_index5 = load i32* %cell_index_ptr
  %current_cell_ptr6 = getelementptr i8* %cells, i32 %cell_index5
  ; Removing this line stops lli segfaulting:
  store i8 0, i8* %current_cell_ptr6
  ret i32 0
}
```

I'm running this code as follows:

```
$ lli example.ll
```

As commented in the code, removing the last `store` prevents `lli` from segfaulting.

Even weirder is that **replacing a variable with its value** also prevents the segfault.

```
; Changing this line prevents the segfault, even though it should be equivalent.
%current_cell_ptr6 = getelementptr i8* %cells, i32 0
```

Why is this? I would have expected `lli` to segfault on `%target_cell_val = load i8* %target_cell_ptr`.

Comment: Did you figure it out? It looks to me like an i8 is missing in the line with the last getelementptr

Comment: @nilsf I ended up avoiding `lli` for debugging my LLVM IR.